# I there any way to DSolve an equation by an estimated method?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, estimation

I am trying to `DSolve` this differential equation for `A[r]`

```
-C1 + r - r*A[r] + 
 (\[Eta]*(-2*Derivative[1][A][r]*(6*A[r] - 6*A[r]^2 + 
      r*Derivative[1][A][r]*(3 + r*Derivative[1][A][r])) + 
    6*r*A[r]*(2 - 2*A[r] + r*Derivative[1][A][r])*Derivative[2][A][r]))/
  r^2
```

It seems that `Mma` cannot solve it. On the other hand, I dont have enough (or exact) data about the boundary conditions to use `NDSolve`. Is there any way to have an estimated solution? Maybe a solution for small values of $\eta$ only.

Comment: Have you seen `AsymptoticDSolveValue[]`?

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon what should I do with B.C.s? Are they necessary here?

Comment: Why not refer to the help page for that function? You should then see that if you don't specify conditions, then it will put up arbitrary constants.